# AMPL Syntax Error - Greater than or equal to issue

Tags: syntax, ampl

I am modeling a sort of schedule optimization problem in AMPL and am using gurobi for the option solver.

In this problem, I have declared a set of schedules from 1 through 1000, and called this set "Schedules".
Each schedule sas a sort of layer (a parameter called "layer" has been created) with a value ranging from 1 to 4. This is a sort of preference or hirearchy of the days off that this particular schedule has.

I want several constraints that determine how many schedules of each preference are available. For instance, I want at least 170 of the schedules to have a preference layer of 1. I wrote the following line to do so:

```
subject to Preference1: sum {j in Schedules: layer[j]=1} >= L1Demand;
```

Where L1Demand is set to 170. However, when I go to include the model file in the ampl window, I get the following error:

```
syntax error 

context:

 subject to Preference1: sum {j in Schedules: layer[j]=1}  >>> >= <<<  L1Demand;
```

I don't understand why this is throwing out a syntax error. I may be missing something very basic or obvious, but can anyone tell me as to why this would be happening? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify an argument for `sum`, for example:

```
sum {j in Schedules: layer[j]=1} x[j]
```

where `x` is some variable indexed over `Schedules`.